# Adding Expandable List View and a normal list View in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to add a Expandable List View and a normal list view in this XML layout when I tried to show the both Expandable List View and a normal list only showing the expandable listview.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ExpandableListView>



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_evevnt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this......

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    androidrientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               >
        </ExpandableListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_evevnt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you can't use both lists like that ... The way I see it, you have 2 options:

1. Either you'll add the second listview items in the first expandablelistview by extending the adapter class: for each item in this expandable that belongs to second listview, you'll have to set child count to zero so you will not have anything to expand. In ExpandableListAdapter#getGroupView() you can return the View from second listview adapter getView
2. There is a project created by Mark Murphy (aka CommonsWare), [CWAC MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) that allows merging different listview and views in a single UI component. Since ExpandableListView is a ListView, then in theory it should work. I used this project successfully but without ExpandableListViews... If it works with these, please let me know

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use This

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weigthSum="1" >
    <LinearLayout android layout_weight=0.5
                  android:layout_height="0dp"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ExpandableListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android layout_weight=0.5
                  android:layout_height="0dp"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"> 

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_evevnt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
   <LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't put 2 list views like that because when you scroll only the first list view will be scrolled .try changing your `layout_height` of `expandablelistview` to a specific dip it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning a android:layout_weight to the ListView element as well. I think you have to have one since you set one for the ExpandableListView.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/10/android-expandablelistview-example.html) tutorial for expandable list view, may this will helpful for you. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should assign
`android:layout_width="0px"` for both views and assign
`android:layout_weight` for listview as well.
`layout_weight` won't work properly without `layout_width` set to `0px`